# How to access child function from parent class

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

```
  class hydra {
    var $dbcon;

    function __construct($ezSQL){
        $this -> dbcon=$ezSQL;
    }

  }
  class user extends hydra{
    function foo(){
       echo "bar is: ".$this->dbcon;
    }
  }
```

I then call:

```
$hydra      = new hydra($ezSQL);
```

However, at this point I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class hydra
```

How do set up a class that will inherit all of it's children's functions so I can do something like this:

```
$hydra = new hydra("foobar");
$hydra -> foo();
```

output:

> bar is: foobar

Comment: You have it completely backwards.  Children have access to their parent's functions, not the other way around.

Comment: Abstract classes can't be instantiated, that's why they're called abstract. And parents don't inherit after children, it's the other way around.

Comment: So there is no way to have a "container" class which you can continue to add extensions too? It just seems counter productive to create X children extending each-other, then to just have a container with all children extending itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not get children's functionality into parent**. Just think, does Mom gets her look from her daughter? No. Its the child who inherits from parent.

The code you have given does not throw any error. But from the error It seems hydra is an abstract class. And as you want to call the childrens method as hydra you should have that method as abstract.

```
abstract class hydra {
    var $dbcon;
    function __construct($ezSQL){
        $this -> dbcon=$ezSQL;
    }
    abstract public function foo();
}
```

Now you can instantiate `user` but call the `foo()` method as `hydra`. Its help full in Type hinting.

```
function dofoo(hydra $h){
    $h->foo();
}
$user = new user("bar");
dofoo($user);
```

Here the function `dofoo` sees `$h` as a `hydra` instance.

Comment: Abstract classes don't have to have abstract methods.

Comment: @danronmoon Are you [sure](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) about it?

Comment: This is sort of what I was looking for. I just don't understand the point of having to initialize two classes When you really only need say, the construct of Hydra and a single function of ONE of it's children. Calling foo() as hydra can only be done if you state in the parent class that the function is an abstract public, correct?

Comment: When you call it **as `hydra`** it must have that class declared.

Comment: My thinking was all wrong, thank's for this. It ended up working. Just as a personal feeling it doesn't make any sense to me. I guess I should just continue to read up and try to understand the parent->child relationship better. Thank you for this!

Comment: @danronmoon, mis-understood you. I thought you were saying abstract class in not mandatory for abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the idea of inheritance wrong.
A parent does not inherit functions from a child, the CHILD inherits functions from the parent.
In your case, `hydra` does not have a function `foo()`.
The class `user` inherits the constructor function and the properties of `hydra`, therefore the code below is what would work.

```
$hydraChild = new user("foobar");
$hydraChild -> foo();
```

Once again, you CANNOT set up a class that inherits all of it's children's functions.
That is not how object-oriented programming works.